# AdSense (AdMob) Reporting Revenue Reporting

Tags: admob, adsense, adsense-api

About the AdSense reporting api - GET  /accounts/accountId/reports

Does it retrieve AdMob only data (as an ad network) or can it include data from other mediated Ad Networks as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [AdMob API](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/getting-started) available to get the AdMob specific data.

It provides a possibility to generate [network](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/reference/rest/v1/accounts.networkReport/generate) and [mediation](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/reference/rest/v1/accounts.mediationReport/generate) reports available. It could be as simple as:

```
curl -X POST https://admob.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/<your_publisher_id>/mediationReport:generate \
       -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" \
       -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
       --data @- << EOF
{
  "report_spec": {
    "date_range": {
      "start_date": {"year": 2020, "month": 4, "day": 1},
      "end_date": {"year": 2020, "month": 4, "day": 1}
    },
    "dimensions": ["AD_SOURCE", "AD_UNIT", "PLATFORM"],
    "metrics": ["ESTIMATED_EARNINGS"]
  }
}
EOF
```

- .net: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/admob/v1
- java: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/google-api-services-admob/v1

Answer (score 0):

if your ad unit included source from other ad network (i.e. mediated), then the AD_REQUESTS, PAGE_VIEWS fields is the total no. of request you sent. But the field INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS represents impressions **served** by admob network, so do the EARNINGS field.

for example, you sent 9000 requests to an ad unit with 3 ad source. Assuming all ad source are made equal, you may see 9000 as AD_REQUESTS, and 3000 as INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS.

There seems to have no way to use adsense reporting api to get the "AdMob Network requests" or "AdMob Network requests RPM"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it does use AdMob, there are some params here for Ad Sense:
https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/metrics-dimensions

Also there is some for AdMob here:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/reporting

You can mix and match and even try your request here to see the output:
https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/reports/generate

We use:

- APP_NAME - the name of your app
- APP_PLATFORM - iOS / Android
- AD_UNIT_SIZE_NAME - this tells us Ad Type, Rewarded, Interstitial etc, in AdMob i think this is Ad Format.

My problem is how to send an authorised request for this from a Unity c# app sitting on a PC but that's a problem for another thread...